# На такой или с таким pattern "[^]" вылетает приложение?

Tags: android, регулярные-выражения, kotlin

```
findText("текст" ,"[^]" , edittext ,edittexterrors ,textview )
        {
            edittext.setText(null)
             var count:Int = 0


            var pattern: Pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern)
            var matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(text!!)


            while (matcher.find())
            {
                count++

                edittext.append(text.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end())+" ");

             }
            textview.setText( count.toString())

        }
```

Comment: Так а вылетает-то чего? Logcat в студию.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja скорее всего на этой строке `var matcher: Matcher = pattern.matcher(text!!)` с НПЕ Editable? - текст в едиттексте null :) `edittext.setText(null)`

Comment: Зачем гадать, стектрейс нам все расскажет. Без Logcat вопрос -- кандидат на закрытие.

Comment: Какой смысл вы хотите вложить, когда пишете  `[^]`?

Comment: Любой символ ,пробел тоже.

Comment: Какие логи выкладывать их там очень много или только отфильтрованные ?

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение `[^abc]` [соответствует](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) любому символу, кроме a, b или c. В вашем примере `[^]` не является правильным регулярным выражением.